# Connecting Action and Outlet to a NIB controller

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a NIB view controller using as a popup menu, I put a UIButton and a UILabel on it, my question is how to connect them to be used in the code area.

For example I declare this:

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *logoImg;
When I go to the nib controller I can not connect the outlet declaration from the .h file to the image on it. I mean it is not like the regular controller.

I hope the question is clear.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First check if you have set the Class name in XIB's file owner.
- If it is done, then try to open the XIB in split mode, you will see the XIB and code classes side by side in cascade mode. In this mode check if the class name is appearing in Automatic section or not.

[image]

- If all goes fine, then try to Bind directly from here.

[image]